# xmlnode insertafter secondchild...or third?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode, css-selectors, insertafter

I know this may seem like a silly question and I have attempted to check msdn documentation and also search this site for some time. I have unfortunately not been able to really understand how to do it.

I would like to insert a node after a second or third child. My XML's main content lies within its grandchildren and when I use root.insertafter I get it put right after very first child.

**XML:**

```
<myCourse>
  <courseName>BEng Mobile and Web Computing</courseName>
  <courseStructure>
    <module>
      <moduleTitle>Programming Methodology</moduleTitle>
      <credits>15</credits>
      <semester>1</semester>
    </module>
    <module>
      <moduleTitle>Computer Systems Fundamentals</moduleTitle>
      <credits>15</credits>
      <semester>1</semester>
    </module>
  </courseStructure>
</myCourse>
```

**And Code:**

```
    private void buttonCreateNode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Load the XML document.
        XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
        document.Load(@"temp.xml");

        // Get the root element.
        XmlElement root = document.DocumentElement;

        // Create the new nodes.
            XmlElement newModule = document.CreateElement("module");
            XmlElement newTitle = document.CreateElement("moduleTitle");
            XmlElement newCredits = document.CreateElement("credits");
            XmlElement newSemester = document.CreateElement("semester");
            XmlText title = document.CreateTextNode("ECA411");
            XmlText credits = document.CreateTextNode("15");
            XmlText semester = document.CreateTextNode("1");

            // Insert the elements.
            newBook.AppendChild(newTitle);
            newBook.AppendChild(newCredits);
            newBook.AppendChild(newSemester);
            newTitle.AppendChild(title);
            newCredits.AppendChild(credits);
            newSemester.AppendChild(semester);
            root.InsertAfter(newModule, root.LastChild);

        document.Save(@"temp.xml");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your help @Mikkelbu.

I have however found a solution to my problem in where to I am now able to accomplish what I was attempting to achieve.

As follows:

```
XmlNode parentNode = document.SelectSingleNode("myCourse/courseStructure/level4");
            parentNode.InsertBefore(newModule, parentNode.FirstChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correct then you want to insert the new module after the module with the title `Computer Systems Fundamentals`. If so then the you need to change the root of the insertion.
So you can change the line

```
XmlElement root = document.DocumentElement;
```

to

```
XmlNode root = document.DocumentElement.LastChild;
```

I would also change the variable name `root` to for instance `courseStructureNode` and the correct the comment accordingly.

Ps. To compile the code you will also need to change `newBook` to `newModule`.